# Java web app redirect to URL depending on where the request came from

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications, spring-boot

I understand the title isn't really great, but I'm not really sure how to explain it so I will describe the scenario.

First of all, I'm using a MVC design.

There are two resources `User` and `Topic`. User info is found at `/users/{id}`, there is an option to browse topics created by that user which redirects to `/users/{id}/topics`. When the user deletes that a topic I want him to send him to `/topics/{id}/delete`, I think that this should be handled by my `TopicController`.

Now the problem: in my `TopicController`, how do I redirect the user back to `/users/{id}/topics`? Normally, when browsing all topics it returns `/topics`. Basically if the request came from user topic list, I need to return him back there after the topic is deleted.

Basically I need a more elegant sollution for

```
if(requestURI.contains("/users") 
   return "redirect:/users/{id}/topics" 
else 
   return "redirect:/topics"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your TopicController handler that maps to `/topics/{id}/delete` you need to do whatever you need to to remove the topic and then something like:

```
    ...
    redirectAttrs.addAttribute("id", account.getId()); 
    return "redirect:/users/{id}/topics";
}
```

Update:-

`/users/{id}`            -> invokes 1 handler which returns user info
`/users/{id}/topics`     -> invokes 1 handler which returns a users topics
`/topics/{id}/delete`      -> invokes 1 handler which deletes a ***users*** topic

If a user deletes his/her topic then shouldn't you always redirect to `/users/{id}/topics` since that is where they were when they chose to remove a topic?

If a user is on `/topics` then they cannot delete a topic right?

Do you ever have a Use Case for directing a user from `/topics/{id}/delete` to `/topics`? I don't think so.

Comment: Sure but if the user is browsing all topics, after he deletes something he will need to be redirected to "/topics". So my controller handler method needs to redirect to two different places depending on circuimstances

Comment: Would be useful if you post your Controller code. Sounds like you do not have enough handlers.  Can't quite appreciate where your use case varies from 1 call to action -> 1 handler -> 1 redirect?

Comment: I haven't written it yet. Basically I need a more elegant sollution for if(requestURI.contains("/users") return "redirect:/users/{id}/topics" else return "redirect:/topics"

Comment: Well there will be a list of all topics which a user can browse, and he will be given an option to delete one or more of them, which will redirect to `/topics/{id}/delete` and afterwards he has to be returned back to the list, which is `/topics`

Comment: what is the difference between what the user sees on `/topics` and what they see on `/users/{id}/topics`? Does `/topics` serve a global list ie. a mashup of all user's topics? If a user is administering their own topics then they would have to be on `/users/{id}/topics` right? In which case, this is where you should return them in case they wish to delete another.

Comment: `/topics` shows all existing topics while `/user/{id}/topics` only show the topics created by that user

Comment: So a user should never be able to delete a Topic whilst browsing `/topics`. In which case if a user deleted a topic like `/users/{id}/topics` -> `/topics/{id}/delete` then they always go back to `/users/{id}/topics` from where they should be able to navigate to `/topics` if they wish. IMHO you are complicating your navigation and therefore your code.

Comment: They will always be able to delete a topic from `/topics`. There are two urls from which they can delete them.